# Redux Toolkit - How to have the payload type checked, when calling an action creator

Tags: typescript, redux

I am using the redux toolkit for some time now and I like how it reduces boilerplate.
I also want to use typescript, but I have trouble to make the typechecking of an action payload work.

f.i. I have:

```
const increase: CaseReducer<AppState, PayloadAction<number>> = (
    state,
    action,
) => {
    state.usedWeight += action.payload;
};
```

and use this in createSlice.
When I want to dispatch that action I write

```
    dispatch(increase(10));
```

but I could also write

```
    dispatch(increase("10"));
```

without typescript complaining.

When I hover the increase in the import in vs code it says:

```
const increase: ActionCreatorWithPayload<any, string> | ActionCreatorWithoutPayload<string>
```

Why does the ActionCreator not know, which Payload this Action is to expect?

Comment: Don't know if it is linked but I noticed that my IDE couldn't also understand exactly what to pass to the action creator as parameters. When hovering it, it show something else that what is expected in the redux-toolkit docs, but doing what is in the doc works

Comment: It is not the IDE, even if I use a wrong type (as above where I give string payload for a number) typescript will build. The problem would be at runtime, when  1 + "10" gives "110"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I had not used the CaseReducer directly in createSlice, but accumulated them in

```
const reducers: ValidateSliceCaseReducers<
    AppState,
    SliceCaseReducers<AppState>
> = {
    ### List of CaseReducers ###
}
```

The typing that I use here broke infering the types for the action creators later.
(I think I got it from redux docs and used them, cause otherwise I would have to add AppState as Type of state to each reducer individually.)

My solution now is to put the CaseReducers directly into the createSlice call.
In order to keep the slice clean, I will put those CaseReducers in subfiles.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

Redux Toolkit provides a type guard with the action creator:
You could test, if `increment.match(action)` is true.
Type checking works then within the if statement, but not outside.

```
        parseInt(action.payload, action.payload); // compiles without any error
        if (increment.match(action)) {
            parseInt(action.payload, action.payload); // here TypeScript produces an error
        }
```

Shouldn't it be possible to ensure type checking without unsing such type guards? I would very much appreciate someone finding a better solution.

Comment: Thx for your comment, I got back to the the redux typescript tutorial and since it is working in my IDE (showing ActionCreatorWithoutPayload on hover as it should), I am narrowing down the issue by removing everything that differs. I will post again when I figured it out, I think something is wrong with the way my Slice is created.